# Why does my excel crash after running my code without an error message?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

The code below crashes at the "END SUB"of the"MAIN" sub.  I have search this and other sites but I can't find a solution.  The frustrating part is the code works perfectly until it crashes. And there is no error message. I don't think the code is very complex and the file I am working with is not very large (6k lines).  I tried copying & pasting the code as well as the data into a fresh workbook.  That did not help.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsData As Worksheet

Sub Main()

    On Error GoTo ProcError

    Dim arrTrading() As Variant    
    Dim arrCenter() As Variant    
    Dim arrCategory() As Variant    
    Dim arrCountry() As Variant   
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    TurnOffFunctionality

    Set wsData = Sheets("State Package Data")
    
    lastRow = getLastRowByEndUp(wsData, 1)
    
    wsData.Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Clear    
    wsData.Range("n2:n" & lastRow).Clear    
    wsData.Range("o2:o" & lastRow).Clear
    
    createArrays arrTrading, arrCenter, arrCategory, arrCountry
    
    lookup arrCountry, lastRow, "j", 20, "n", 8, "country"   
    lookup arrCategory, lastRow, "f", 1, "m", 3, "category"
    lookup arrTrading, lastRow, "j", 1, "o", 3, "trading partner"
         
    TurnOnFunctionality
    
ProcError:
  MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

```
Sub lookup(arr As Variant, lastRow As Long, lookupCol As String, matchCol As Long, _
           postCol As String, returnCol As Long, name As String)

    Dim i As Long  
    Dim x As Long 
    Dim lookupValue As String   
    Dim matchValue As String
        
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
        lookupValue = wsData.Cells(i, lookupCol)
        
        For x = 2 To UBound(arr)
        
            matchValue = arr(x, matchCol)
        
            If lookupValue = matchValue Then                               
                wsData.Cells(i, postCol) = arr(x, returnCol)                
                Exit For            
            End If
        
        Next x
    
    Next i

    Debug.Print name
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub createArrays(arrTrading As Variant, arrCenter As Variant, arrCategory As Variant, arrCountry As Variant)

    Sheets("Mapping").Activate
    
    arrCategory = Range("g1").CurrentRegion    
    arrCenter = Range("k1").CurrentRegion
    arrTrading = Range("n1").CurrentRegion
    
    Sheets("BPC Consol Ownership").Activate
    
    arrCountry = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what happens when it "crashes"?

Comment: The application (Excel) shutdowns.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your code.  Any event handlers in your worksheet?  Maybe try adding `Exit Sub` above `ProcError` so your code doesn't run into it in normal execution.

Comment: There are not event handlers in my worksheet.  I added the Exit Sub above the ProcError and it still crashed.  I also copy & pasted the data and code for a third time into a new workbook. This makes no sense.

Comment: What's in `TurnOnFunctionality` ?  Without the `Exit Sub` were you seeing the messagebox?

Comment: TurnOnFunctionality activates screenupdating , automatic calculation and status updates.  The code was too long so I had to leave off two small subs. Do you want to see code for it? I do see a message box without the Exit Sub, but it is blank.

Comment: if you comment out those calls does it still crash?  And the messagebox?

Comment: Yes it still crashes when I comment out 'TurnOnFunctionality'

Comment: I'm out of guesses/questions...

Comment: One more thing.  It does work if I run `lookup` sub once.  For instance, if I comment out two of three `lookup` sub in any combination, it works.

Comment: How are you running `Main` ? From a button or ??

Comment: I run main from the editor

Comment: You may want to 'properly' finish `Main`: 1. `ProcExit` 2. `TurnOnFunctionality` 3. `Exit Sub` 4. `ProcError:` 5. `MsgBox Err.Description` 6. `Resume ProcExit` 7. `End Sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of error you get is usually caused by the code's inability to continue, such as might be the case if `TurnOnFunctionality` would quit the Excel application or delete the workbook in which the code resides.

It might also be caused by the ActiveSheet being lost. In the `createArrays` procedure you change the ActiveSheet: `Sheets("BPC Consol Ownership").Activate` and never change it back. Perhaps `TurnOnFunctionality` tries to select a cell on a sheet that isn't active anymore. This is terrible coding:-

```
Sheets("BPC Consol Ownership").Activate
arrCountry = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
```

`arrCountry` appears to be a range (as are `arrCategory`, `arrCenter` and `arrTrading` which are on another sheet). Now, what is this?

```
    If lookupValue = matchValue Then
        wsData.Cells(i, postCol) = Arr(x, returnCol)
        Exit For
    End If
```

- `postCol` and `returnCol` are both strings.
- `wsData,Cells(i, postCol)` and `Arr(x, returnCol)` are both ranges. Are they?
- The syntax forces comparison of their respective `Value` properties. Therefore the real code behind your code might be `wsData,Cells(i, postCol).Value = Arr(x, returnCol).Value`, where `Arr` isn't an array but a range - and a range on a worksheet which we can't take the time to figure out in which relationship it stands with *wsData* or the *ActiveSheet*.

This conflation of range and value is permeating your code. Combined with the unwholesome switching of the *ActiveSheet*, obviously, a situation arises where not only I am confused but even Excel. Therefore:-

1. Remove all `Activate` and `Select` statements from your code.
2. Remove all ambiguity from your procedures. Use `arrCountry = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value` and deal with the consequences thereof.

As you see from the latter advice, if your intention were to assign the range to *arrCountry* the syntax should be `Set arrCountry = Range("a1").CurrentRegion` and then `Arr(x, returnCol)` would indeed be a cell that is correctly addressed with `returnCol` as a string. But if `Arr` is an array then `returnCol` can't be a string and the final failure must be related to this syntax error, so deeply burried in your code that even Excel can't identify the source and therefore just crashes without explanation.

Comment: Thank you.  I made your changes and the code works.